# Kivy: bind method inside the .kv file

Tags: kivy

I would like to delete this line from my .py file:

```
self.layout.bind(minimum_height=self.layout.setter('height'))
```

and replace it by the same instruction but in the .kv file. Is there any way to bind `self.layout.setter('height')` to `minimum_height` ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

How about?

```
height: self.minimum_height
```

I am guessing you use that in a ScrollView. If true this should work.
See for example this post https://stackoverflow.com/a/45313388/6646710 which uses exactly that.

Answer (score 1):

To adapt layout height to child widgets's height you can simply do:

```
height: self.minimum_height
```

**Example:**

- **Only python code:**

  ```
  from kivy.app import App
  from kivy.uix.gridlayout import GridLayout
  from kivy.uix.button import Button
  from kivy.uix.boxlayout import BoxLayout 
  from kivy.uix.scrollview import ScrollView



  class RootWidget(BoxLayout):
      def __init__(self, **kwargs): 
          super(RootWidget, self).__init__(**kwargs)
          self.orientation = "vertical"
          self.sv = ScrollView()
          self.btn = Button(text="Addd button", size_hint_y=0.1, 
                                        on_press = self.add_button)
          self.layout = GridLayout(cols = 1, size_hint_y= None, 
                                              row_default_height= 100)
          self.layout.bind(minimum_height=self.layout.setter('height'))
          self.add_widget(self.sv)
          self.add_widget(self.btn)
          self.sv.add_widget(self.layout)

      def add_button(self, instance):
          self.layout.add_widget(Button())


  class TestApp(App):
      def build(self):
          return RootWidget()

  if __name__ == '__main__':
      TestApp().run()
  ```
- **Using Kivy Languaje:**

  **main.py:**

  ```
  from kivy.app import App
  from kivy.uix.gridlayout import GridLayout
  from kivy.uix.button import Button
  from kivy.uix.boxlayout import BoxLayout 



  class RootWidget(BoxLayout):
      def __init__(self, **kwargs): 
          super(RootWidget, self).__init__(**kwargs)

      def add_button(self):
          self.layout.add_widget(Button())


  class TestApp(App):
      def build(self):
          return RootWidget()

  if __name__ == '__main__':
      TestApp().run()
  ```

  **test.kv:**

  ```
  <RootWidget>:
      orientation: "vertical"
      layout: glayout
      ScrollView:
          GridLayout
              id: glayout
              cols:1
              row_default_height: 100
              size_hint_y: None
              height: self.minimum_height  # <<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<

      Button:
          text: "Add button"
          on_press: root.add_button()
          size_hint_y: 0.1
  ```

Answer (score 0):

You can do `height: self.minimum_height` in the .kv file. Just keep in mind that sometimes you will also have to set `size_hint_y: None` to see the desired effect.