# How to make changes to global object attribute with Kivy TextInput and have it save for later use?

Tags: python, kivy, global-variables

My app currently has 10 "players" with a name, offensive rating, and defensive rating. I want to give the user the opportunity to change the names of the players before running my game simulation code, but it appears I can only temporarily change the name inside of the current screen. Here's my current python code for when the user inputs the name from the gui:

```
class SecondWindow(Screen):
    def pg1_name_val(self, widget):
    pg1.name = widget.text
```

If I code in a print(pg1.name) right below that, it will print the correct name, but when the user hits "play" to shift to a results screen, the names go back to the default names.

How do I make pg1.name from my SecondWindow(Screen) become the global pg1.name? Is there a simple line of code I can use to return pg1.name as the global variable?

EDIT ----

So I've came a long way with my app this week, but now that I want to have a separate "results" screen, I've realized that I lost all of my data from the previous screen. It looks like all of the changes I make to my "players" are going back to defaults once the screen changes. I'll paste some code below for reference. Basically, my question now is this: Is there a way to keep the objects from one screen and return them back as the global instance of the object. Not just the local instance of the object.

.py -

```
class Player():
def __init__(self,name,off,deff):
    self.name = name
    self.off = off
    self.deff = deff
    self.stats = 0
```

class Team():
def **init**(self,pg, sg, sf, pf, c):
self.pg = pg
self.sg = sg
self.sf = sf
self.pf = pf
self.c = c
self.score = 0
self.results = None
self.to = 0

On the screen where I'm creating my team, I have a button to run the simulation. This button runs the sim correctly, records all of the game results in a string, prints all of the results to the console, attributes, and score correctly. The button also changes the screen to where I want to display a scroll view of the results string, but the results are empty.

I'd really appreciate any help on this, as I'm at a roadblock. Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It would kinda look the same. Depending on how exactly you wanna keep the 10 different players.

```
class Player():
    def __init__(self, name, off, deff):
        self.name = name
        self.off = off
        self.deff = deff
        self.stats = 0

player = [Player('', 0, 0)] * 10


class SecondWindow(Screen):
    def __init__(self, **kwargs):
        super(SecondWindow, self).__init__(**kwargs)
        self.player = player

    def name_change(self):
        self.player[0].name = self.ids.name.text
        player[0].name = self.player[0].name


    def next_screen(self):
        self.manager.current = 'result'


class ResultWindow(Screen):
    def __init__(self, **kwargs):
        super(ResultWindow, self).__init__(**kwargs)

    def on_enter(self, *args):
        print(player[0].name)


class Manager(ScreenManager):
    pass


class Player(App):
    def build(self):
        sm = ScreenManager()
        sm.add_widget(SecondWindow(name='second'))
        sm.add_widget(ResultWindow(name='result'))
        return sm


if __name__ == '__main__':
    Player().run()
```

You would have to work with OOP, here I created a list of you player object for all ten players it is an easy way to keep the code short.
You might like to keep them as 10 different objects the good part of a list it is easy to iterate through in a for loop and then get all the data for a stats board on a screen and also easy to expand later if you need 20 players or more.

I didn't change anything in the .kv file.

.kv

```
<SecondWindow>:
    TextInput:
        id: name
        hint_text: 'Player name'
        size: 260, 32
        pos: (root.width / 2) - (self.width / 2), 248
        multiline: False
        on_text_validate: root.name_change()
    Button:
        id: create_btn
        text: 'Next Screen'
        size: 260, 32
        pos: (root.width / 2) - (self.width / 2), 206
        color: utils.get_color_from_hex('#ffffff')
        background_color: utils.get_color_from_hex('#016bf8')
        on_press: root.next_screen()

<ResultWindow>:
    Label:
        id: name
```

The on_text_validate only works with multiline false and when enter is pressed if you don't want to press enter user on_text instead.

--Edit--

I did some research this morning and thought maybe to update this a bit with my findings.
You could instead of doing it the import to all screens do it in the screenmanager and just call it from the screen like this:

pyhon.py

```
import kivy
from kivy.app import App
from kivy.lang import Builder
from kivy.uix.screenmanager import ScreenManager, Screen


class Player:
    def __init__(self, name, off, deff):
        self.name = name
        self.off = off
        self.deff = deff
        self.stats = 0


class SecondWindow(Screen):
    def __init__(self, **kwargs):
        super(SecondWindow, self).__init__(**kwargs)

    def name_change(self):
        self.manager.player.name = self.ids.name.text


    def next_screen(self):
        self.manager.current = 'result'


class ResultWindow(Screen):
    def __init__(self, **kwargs):
        super(ResultWindow, self).__init__(**kwargs)

    def on_enter(self):
        self.ids.name.text = self.manager.player.name


class Manager(ScreenManager):
    player = Player('', 0, 0)

    def __init__(self, **kwargs):
        super(Manager, self).__init__(**kwargs)


class PlayerApp(App):
    def build(self):
        return Builder.load_file('test.kv')


if __name__ == '__main__':
    PlayerApp().run()
```

the kv file would look something like this:

.kv

```
#:import utils kivy.utils
Manager:
    SecondWindow:
        name: 'second'
    ResultWindow:
        name: 'result'

<SecondWindow>:
    TextInput:
        id: name
        hint_text: 'Player name'
        size: 260, 32
        size_hint: None, None
        pos: (root.width / 2) - (self.width / 2), 248
        multiline: False
        on_text_validate: root.name_change()
    Button:
        id: create_btn
        text: 'Next Screen'
        size_hint: None, None
        size: 260, 32
        pos: 0, 0
        color: utils.get_color_from_hex('#ffffff')
        background_color: utils.get_color_from_hex('#016bf8')
        on_press: root.next_screen()

<ResultWindow>:
    Label:
        id: name
```

hope it helps

Comment: Thanks for the reply Dobbeltop. Most of my python code runs off of the Player class having a offensive and defensive attribute assigned. From the code you provided, it looks like calling the global variable in the __init__ function of the screen class made the global variable editable in the screen. Is that right? If so, could the following

def __init__(self, **kwargs):
        super(SecondWindow, self).__init__(**kwargs)
        self.pg1 = pg1

make the global object "pg1" editable inside of the screen? I hope my question makes sense. I'm trying to use the correct terminology, but noob

Comment: You would make an instance of the class inside the screen. So you would be able to edit everything but without returning it to the global class you wouldn't get the data back to the class. Can you edit your post with the full player class then I would be able to help you better. We have all been the noobs at some point that is why we have this place. :-)

Comment: Ha Thanks for your patience Dobbeltop. I've edited my original post. It would be awesome if have time to take a look and offer some suggestions.

Comment: I have updated my answer to reflect the changes. And come with the best suggestions I could.

Comment: It's interesting. On the results screen, I can add a button to print results to the console, and that button works great. But on the same screen, if I try to display the results on the screen and not just in the console, it reverts back to default. How is that?

Comment: Did you remember to do the self.player = player like on the first screen? because i didn't have a problem doing self.ids.name.text = self.player[0].name it added the name i wrote on the first screen. If this don't work. add you code to your post and i will see where it goes wrong. :)

Comment: I'll try that when i get home. Just so I understand, when I say in a screen that self.player = player, is that how I let the screen know that the object "player" that is being used in the screen is the global variable? So if, for instance, I had an object with a Team class, i could say self.team1 = team1.. and that would let my program know I want to use and make changes to the global "team1" variable?

Seriously Dobbel, you rock!

Comment: Not really because you could just not do it and it would in large scale do the same. But when you do self.player = player it just good practice to make your code look more readable and people would understand it comes outside of the class you would have to player.name = self.player.name to return it to the global variable. Doing self.team1 = team1 would like when you define a normal class just move the global variable into the self.team1 and then you would have to return it to the team1 after. Thank you i am just happy to help. Like you i learn new things everyday too. And that is fun. :)

Comment: Take a look at this depending on how big your scrollview is gonna be.https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45307121/how-to-use-scrollbar-in-kivy-python look at the comment under the answer might be interesting for you

Comment: Thanks so much for the help. I have it working now. 

I had to recalculate my StringProperty in the results page. I guess when I initially run my code, the { results_text = StringProperty(game.results) } line that sits at the top of my results page is set. so the variable "results_text" is given the defaults and when I got to the third page, it was never updated. I fixed it by adding a line of code to the button that takes you to that page to update results_text. 

Now I just have to figure out what I'm doing wrong with the ScrollView widget, but I'll figure out with some searching